# Fastest way to format a column with openpyxl (Python)

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm using Openpyxl and applying number formatting for a dynamically determined number of columns and rows (based on available data), e.g.

```
ws.cell(row=i, column=idx + 1).number_format = '_(* #,##0.00_);_(* (#,##0.00);_(* "-"??_);_(@_)'
```

It takes a long time to format some of the bigger workbooks.

All I'm trying to accomplish is creating workbooks that treat integers and floats as numbers (either no decimal places or two decimal places), rather than strings, and I want that for all `idx` columns.  I've read that it's possible, presumably related to this: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/styles/numbers.html but I'm not sure how to implement this.

Comment: You might get better performance using a named style but there are no real shortcuts here: the style information for every cell must be changed.

Comment: Why don't you convert the strings to float before 'inserting' them into the Workbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are trying to accomplish is just to make Excel treat numbers well, as numbers and not like strings you can try converting them to float in python. This method is almost 50% faster than assigning format to each cell;

```
ws.cell(row=i, column=idx + 1).value = float(ws.cell(row=i, column=idx + 1).value)
```

Comment: I tested this for 100000 numbers in a column, and assigning cell format to each cell took `0.6240622997283936` while converting the value in python and assigning it back took only `0.3340334892272949`